# Getting an executable output in Azure Pipeline's PowerShell@2

Tags: powershell, logging, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to debug my code because it isn't working on the pipeline. It is working locally. I have C# code that writes to both the Console.Out and Console.Error in my executable. Neither is being outputted to the Task output. How do I copy my output from the executable onto the PowerShell task?

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Create Link
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      '& ./CreateShortcut.exe
      --icon $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PI_Icon.ico
      --shortcutPath $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Temp.lnk
      --exe ./Bin/Application/Temp.exe'
    workingDirectory: 'Temp/BuildEvents/CreateShortcut/bin/Debug/net48'
    showWarnings: true
```

Comment: I don't know how the code is passed to PowerShell via your YAML file, but your call wouldn't work locally _without line continuations_.

Comment: The | makes it multiline.

Comment: But unless someone converts the newlines to spaces, you'll end up with a broken PowerShell command, because commands require arguments to be on the same line - except if you use line continuation (a `\`` at the very end of each interior line).

Comment: It works on yaml for Azure Devops. There is probably some conversion going on under the hood. 
Actually, my problem is from adding custom arguments '--icon' to my executable instead of just strings.

Comment: If `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` expands to a value _with spaces_, you'll  have to use embedded quoting around it.

Comment: That wasn't causing a problem. Everything was working before I added the '--' to my executable arguments.

This isn't straight up PowerShell. It's a task written for the azure devops pipeline. If it was straight powershell, I'd having it working already.

Comment: So the command works as expected if you remove the parameter _names_ (e.g, `--icon`) from your calls? And when it fails, there is no indication whatsoever what went wrong? I suggest updating your question to clarify.

Comment: It turns out that when I added in the arguments, I introduced a bug where the program would always fail. The program had an exit code that was not being outputted by PowerShell. My question was on how to output that exit code.

Comment: If you want to print the exit code _to stdout_ (in addition to reporting it), append `; $LASTEXITCODE; exit $LASTEXITCODE` to your command. `exit $LASTEXITCODE` is also needed if you want the _specific_ exit code to be reported, because the implied `-Command` PowerShell CLI execution would otherwise map _any nonzero_ exit code to `1`.